# jQuery: How to use .each() once per item as it loops

Tags: jquery

I have a small jQuery script that is designed to copy an external form input label and stick it inside the form input (to make a system-generated form look nicer):

jQuery to move input labels inside inputs:

```
$('.formFieldLabel').each(function( index ) {
    var labels = $(this).text();
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $(this).parentsUntil("table").find('.formFieldText, .formTextArea').val(labels);
    };
})
```

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="formFieldLabel" >
First Name</td>
<td class="formFieldLabel" style="padding-left: 5px">
Last Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >
<input type="text" class="l6e formFieldText formFieldMediumLeft" id="form_0048_fld_1_fn" name="First Name" value="">
</td>
<td style="padding-left: 5px">
<input type="text" class="l6e formFieldText formFieldMediumRight" id="form_0048_fld_1_ln" name="Last Name" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="formFieldLabel">
Email Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="Email" class="l6e formFieldText formFieldLarge" id="form_0048_fld_1_em" name="E-mail Address" value="">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Currently, it sets the value inside the input to be the last-processed item that .each() touches, rather than doing one input and them moving onto the next. I realize I'm missing something obvious here in all likelihood, but what could it be?

Comment: there is no such thing as `.formTextArea`

Comment: Your are selecting __all__ elements with class `formFieldText` or `formTextArea` in __each__ loop iteration, and set the current value on all of them – and therefor you _end up_ with only the last value in the end. See to it, that you target only the specific form element in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there's a 1:1 relationship between the labels and inputs, you could reference the index to filter the input from your selection.

http://jsfiddle.net/bwZaH/

```
$('.formFieldLabel').each(function( index ) {
    var labels = $(this).text();
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $(this).parentsUntil("table").find('.formFieldText, .formTextArea').eq(index).val(labels);
    };
})
```

***Edit!***

If you can make changes to the mark up, I'd recommend updating your text to use `<label>` elements. Point the `for` attribute to your input (making it more accessible) and simplifying your jQuery loop. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<td class="formFieldLabel" >
    <label for="form_0048_fld_1_fn">First Name</label>
</td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('label').each(function(index) {
    var labels = $(this).text();
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).val(labels);
    };
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bwZaH/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the name attribute to find them. (You'd have to change your email name attr).

```
$('.formFieldLabel').each(function (index) {
    var labels = $(this).text();
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $('[name="' + labels + '"]').val(labels);
    };
})
```

The reason what you have isn't working, is that is is finding and setting all `.formFieldText, .formTextArea` each time.

http://jsfiddle.net/E3JfE/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is : For each value you get from the `.formFieldLabel` fields, you modify the value of all the `input` fields. So the ending state is : every `input` contain the last value found ...

You need to filter the selection of `input` to modify with an `.eq()` jquery selector.

And if you want to associate the fields, line by line :

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    tr.find('.formFieldLabel').each(function(index){
        tr.next('tr')
          .find('.formFieldText, .formTextArea')
          .eq(index)
          .val($(this).html());
    });
});
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Y43DS/)